# Load a json file from biq query command line

Tags: json, google-bigquery

Is it possible to load data from a json file (not just csv) using the Big Query command line tool?  I am able to load a simple json file using the GUI, however, the command line is assuming a csv, and I don't see any documentation on how to specify json.

Here's the simple json file I'm using

{"col":"value"}

With schema
col:STRING

Comment: Additional support for JSON was announced today. http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/10/got-big-json-bigquery-expands-data.html

Comment: That's great! However, it doesn't look like the command line api has been modified since 9/11, and the current version, 2.0.9, is telling me it doesn't now about the source_format flag.

Comment: Are we limited at loading one partition at a time? Need a wrapper script to load everything?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does not support JSON formatted data loading.
Here is the documentation (`bq help load`) for the `load`command with the latest bq version 2.0.9:

```
USAGE: bq [--global_flags] <command> [--command_flags] [args]


load     Perform a load operation of source into destination_table.

     Usage:
     load <destination_table> <source> [<schema>]

     The <destination_table> is the fully-qualified table name of table to create, or append to if the table already exists.

     The <source> argument can be a path to a single local file, or a comma-separated list of URIs.

     The <schema> argument should be either the name of a JSON file or a text schema. This schema should be omitted if the table already has one.

     In the case that the schema is provided in text form, it should be a comma-separated list of entries of the form name[:type], where type will default
     to string if not specified.

     In the case that <schema> is a filename, it should contain a single array object, each entry of which should be an object with properties 'name',
     'type', and (optionally) 'mode'. See the online documentation for more detail:
     https://code.google.com/apis/bigquery/docs/uploading.html#createtable

     Note: the case of a single-entry schema with no type specified is
     ambiguous; one can use name:string to force interpretation as a
     text schema.

     Examples:
     bq load ds.new_tbl ./info.csv ./info_schema.json
     bq load ds.new_tbl gs://mybucket/info.csv ./info_schema.json
     bq load ds.small gs://mybucket/small.csv name:integer,value:string
     bq load ds.small gs://mybucket/small.csv field1,field2,field3

     Arguments:
     destination_table: Destination table name.
     source: Name of local file to import, or a comma-separated list of
     URI paths to data to import.
     schema: Either a text schema or JSON file, as above.

     Flags for load:

/usr/local/bin/bq:
  --[no]allow_quoted_newlines: Whether to allow quoted newlines in CSV import data.
  -E,--encoding: <UTF-8|ISO-8859-1>: The character encoding used by the input file. Options include:
    ISO-8859-1 (also known as Latin-1)
    UTF-8
  -F,--field_delimiter: The character that indicates the boundary between columns in the input file. "\t" and "tab" are accepted names for tab.
  --max_bad_records: Maximum number of bad records allowed before the entire job fails.
    (default: '0')
    (an integer)
  --[no]replace: If true erase existing contents before loading new data.
    (default: 'false')
  --schema: Either a filename or a comma-separated list of fields in the form name[:type].
  --skip_leading_rows: The number of rows at the beginning of the source file to skip.
    (an integer)

gflags:
  --flagfile: Insert flag definitions from the given file into the command line.
    (default: '')
  --undefok: comma-separated list of flag names that it is okay to specify on the command line even if the program does not define a flag with that name.
    IMPORTANT: flags in this list that have arguments MUST use the --flag=value format.
    (default: '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you happen to know why the GUI supports it?  Is the GUI converting json to csv?  Seems like quite a performance hit if it had to convert a 100MB file (ui file size limit)

Comment: I guess the GUI does the conversion work on its side. The file size limit is 4GB not 100MB?

Comment: Hmm, I could've swore I saw that the GUI file limit was 100MB, but now I can't find it.

Answer (score 10):

As of version 2.0.12, bq does allow uploading newline-delimited JSON files.  This is an example command that does the job:

```
bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON datasetName.tableName data.json schema.json
```

As mentioned above, "bq help load" will give you all of the details.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes you can

2) The documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool-quickstart?hl=en#createtable) . Go to step 3: Upload the table in documentation.

3) You have to use --source_format flag to tell the bq that you are uploading a JSON file and not a csv.

4) The complete commmand structure is

```
bq load [--source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON] [--project_id=your_project_id] destination_data_set.destination_table data_source_uri table_schema

bq load --project_id=my_project_bq dataset_name.bq_table_name gs://bucket_name/json_file_name.json path_to_schema_in_your_machine
```

5) You can find other bq load variants by

```
bq help load
```